ANOVA finding a main effect prevents inflation of Type I error rate
In the (free) book Understanding Statistics and Experimental Design, section 6.3, they say

'...ANOVA offers a second trick. If we rejected the null hypothesis, it is appropriate to compare pairs of means with what are called “post-hoc tests,” which, roughly speaking, corresponds to computing pairwise comparisons. Contrary to the
multiple testing situations discussed in Chap. 5, these multiple comparisons do not inflate the Type I error rate because they are only conducted if the ANOVA finds a main effect.'

Why does ANOVA finding a main effect prevent inflation of the Type I error rate?
At least one other book seems to imply that inflation of the Type I error rate does need to be corrected for when conducting post-hoc tests. And the JASP screenshot below seems also to indicate that a correction is necessary.


On the same page as the quote (p.71), the second and third hypotheses are the same.  On the next page, the author claims ANOVA assumes: "The sample size is determined before the experiment," which is absurd. Of course justifying your sample size before going out to collect data is a good idea, but there is nothing about ANOVA that invalidates its use if the sample size was not decided in advance.


...these multiple comparisons do not inflate the Type I error rate because they are only conducted if the ANOVA finds a main effect.

This is an example of right for the wrong reasons.
Even if the omnibus test is significant, pairwise comparisons still have an inflated family-wise error rate (FWER). The effect of this can be, that while there are indeed significant differences, there are not as many as the pairwise comparisons suggest.
The pairwise comparisons conducted in the post hoc of an ANOVA do protect against the inflated FWER, but not for the reason provided.
The protection against false positives among the pairwise comparisons is simply... a correction for multiple comparisons. For example, the Tukey correction in the question, is part of Tukey's honest significant difference test which uses the studentized range distribution to correct for the FWER.
The two-stage testing approach is supposed to help in borderline cases, where one (multiple testing corrected) pairwise comparison happens to be significant, while the overall variance in means is too small for the omnibus test to be significant. But it does not magically solve the multiple comparisons problem for individual pairwise tests.
See also this somewhat related post: T-test, ANOVA or Regression, what's the difference?

Thank you, Frans!
